# Javascript Paginated

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this jQuery

```
$('table.paginated').each(function() {
    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = 10;
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
    var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
            newPage: page
        }, function(event) {
            currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
    }
    $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Xugej/ to paginate

I want a function to remove the pagination.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you don't want pagination, then don't include the code to paginate.

Comment: I need to paginate and remove in some case

Comment: do you mean to undo the pagination? To return back to the state that was before pagination applying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following and show the hidden tr elements and hide the pager div

http://jsfiddle.net/hg766/

Html

```
<div class="remove">Remove</div>
```

JQuery click action

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $('.pager').hide();
    $('tr').show();
});
```